# unity networking: bullets not showing on the server when spawned by the client

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I am making a simple 2D shooting game. Movements currently appear on both sides of the server fine, however bullets only appear on the server if the host creates them. If the client makes bullets, they cannot been seen by the host (but can be seen by the client), so I presume that they are not being spawned on the server. As the host works but the client doesn't, I do not understand why this problem occurs and how it works, so if someone could explain it to me, that would be great...

Comment: From memory, you have to call something like "Spawn" in order to tell the server to also host the object.  I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a case of creating the object on the server, perhaps with a client call that initiates that process.  Then, the server will `Spawn` that object, and send the object to all clients also.

See here for a detailed guide:  https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetSpawning.html

Most notably, check the "Object Creation Flow" section.